# System context mismatch error when running simulation

Tags: drake

I am building a manipulation scenario that follows the general instructions as described in the [MakeManipulationStation](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/396fe7c40b5881a58bbb5b8f083b70c1c11bd94f/manipulation/scenarios.py) script. The general idea is that you declare 2 multi-body plants, each for the physics engine and the controller to use as their internal models. The `ManipulationStation` diagram (consisting of the physics engine and controller multibodyplants) is then built and used as a sub-diagram inside the `pick-n-place` diagram, with relevant ports connected.

In my setting, I have tried to follow the same idea as follows. I created an `AssemblyStation` by creating 2 multibody plants, each representing the physics engine and the relevant controller (a custom leaf implementation). The `controller_plant` is used to add the `iiwa_impedance_controller` system. This built diagram is then used as a subsystem inside an outer diagram `peg-in-hole`.

After going ahead and performing all the initialisations and running the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peginsert.py", line 990, in <module>
    main()
  File "peginsert.py", line 837, in main
    simulator.AdvanceTo(t)
  File "peginsert.py", line 407, in TauCalcOutput
    V_WS_W = self._S.CalcSpatialVelocity(
RuntimeError: A function call on a drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> system named '::control_plant' was passed the Context of a system named '::peg-in-hole::AssemblyStation::iiwa_impedance_controller' instead of the appropriate subsystem Context.
For more information about Context-System mismatches, see https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html#framework-context-system-mismatch
```

I realise that this error has a trouble shooting page dedicated to it, but I have not pinpointed the exact source.

How do I debug this?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Your `control_plant` is being passed the wrong context. So, you should look at your use of the `control_plant`'s APIs where you're passing it a context. Where did you get that context from?

Typically, the physics plant is part of the diagram and its context is embedded in the full simulation diagram's context. The control plant is usually a wholly-owned instance of the controller (to do various kinematics computations). It needs to have its own context and the controller that owns the context will be responsible for allocating that plant's context (and updating its state to reflect the state of the physics plant). You can see that in the `InverseDynamics` system. It stores its plant's context in a cache entry and updates it when its "estimated_state" input changes.

Comment: Currently, the controller recieves the context through its `Output` port event handler. Furthermore, for other context related information I have declared a class level variable that stores the `control_plant.CreateDefaultContext`.  Is there somewhere I can read how the `InverseDynamicsController` handles the physics' plant context? Thanks for the help

Comment: "receives the context through its Output port event handler"  I assume you to mean the `Context` passed in as a parameter to the event handler. That is not the `Context` for `control_plant`. It's the `Context` for the `peg-in-hole` controller. You've allocated `control_plant`'s context. That's good. But you want to keep it up to date. I'd suggest looking at the C++ implementation of the InverseDynamics (https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/systems/controllers/inverse_dynamics.cc) system. It does the same thing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I understand the problem now. However, I am running into issues with regards to the `DeclareCacheEntry` class. I have tried the following according to the `InverseDynamics` implementation
`
        self._plant_context_cache_index = self.DeclareCacheEntry(
                "plant_context_cache",
                self._plant_context,
                self.CalcCacheValue,
                set([self.input_port_ticket(self._joint_vel_index)])
                ).cache_index()

`
However, it looks like I used a wrong interface to the `DeclareCacheEntry` class

Comment: Is there anywhere I can see how to utilise this class in python? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with *using* the python bindings. However, this test, https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/systems/test/custom_test.py#L1027-L1042, uses a slightly different spelling than the C++ in inverse dynamics. The bindings are documented ,https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.framework.html?highlight=declarecacheentry#pydrake.systems.framework.SystemBase.DeclareCacheEntry. The only thing missing in the test example is the specification of `prerequisites_of_calc`. Let me know if that helps you get over the obstacle.